# from nets.mobilenet import mobilenet_v3 ImportError: cannot import name 'mobilenet_v3'

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, object-detection, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I followed this tutorial (https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) in ubuntu 16.04 (CPU version). Followed all the steps properly but stuck while giving the command

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

I am getting this error:  (everything was fine, except at the end.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

*File "train.py", line 52, in module*          

*from object_detection.builders import model_builder*
  *File "/home/user2/tf1.12/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 47, in module*

*from object_detection.models.ssd_mobilenet_edgetpu_feature_extractor import SSDMobileNetEdgeTPUFeatureExtractor*

*File"/home/user2/tf1.12/models/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_edgetpu_feature_extractor.py", line 19, in module*

*from object_detection.models import ssd_mobilenet_v3_feature_extractor*

*File"/home/user2/tf1.12/models/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v3_feature_extractor.py", line 26, in <module>*

*from nets.mobilenet import mobilenet_v3*

*ImportError: cannot import name 'mobilenet_v3'*
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first and make modifications to you question

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!